# Need an efficient way to turn (Seq Data.Text) to Data.Text

Tags: haskell

I have a program (a SAX parser using `Text.XML.Expat.SAX`) that builds up very big CDATA nodes using repeated appends of `Data.Text` content, using `Data.Sequence.(|>)` like so:

```
existingText |> newTextChunk
```

This builds up a very big piece of data of type `Seq Text`.

After I've built up the data, I need to convert the `Seq Text -> Text`. But this solution I tried was super-slow:

```
Data.Foldable.foldr1 Data.Text.append seqText
```

Is there a faster way to turn a Sequence of Text into a plain Text datum?

Another way to ask this might be, what's the most efficient way to do merge a list of Text into one Text, i.e. `[Text] -> Text`?

Comment: I would expect the answer to the last question is [`concat`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/text/0.11.3.1/doc/html/Data-Text.html#v:concat). Have you tried that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`append` will create a new array for every element in the list, and copy all data to it. As one of the comments said you might want to try `concat`. For sequence you could try doing:

```
import Data.Foldable (toList)
import Data.Sequence (Seq)
import qualified Data.Sequence as S
import Data.Text (Text)
import qualified Data.Text as T

concatSeq :: Seq Text -> Text
concatSeq = T.concat . toList
```

This should be faster than doing a `fold` with `append`, but I haven't verified it. You could try to whip up a small test case using criterion (which is an amazing library).